# asterisk 12 webrtc no media

Tags: sip, asterisk, webrtc

I am currently facing an issue on webrtc, When I call on server using [sipml5](http://sipml5.org/) I am not able to listen to any audio prompt playing on the server. Also using `rtp` set debug on, only packets are sent, no packets are being received on server.
as it is mentioned below :

```
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012353, ts 063784, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012354, ts 063944, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012355, ts 064104, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012356, ts 064264, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012357, ts 064424, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012358, ts 064584, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012359, ts 064744, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012360, ts 064904, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012361, ts 065064, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012362, ts 065224, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012363, ts 065384, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012364, ts 065544, len 000164)
Sent RTP packet to      122.161.XX.XX:49819 (type 00, seq 012365, ts 065704, len 000164)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug these kind of issues is to use a network debugging tool (for example [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) on the client side. By examining the outgoing RTC/RTP traffic, you can get closer to what's wrong and how to solve it.

A few examples:

- packets going to wrong IP -> network settings in asterisk or the client
- no packet going out at all -> no audio is getting to the browser

Look for small UDP packets in the high (>10000) UDP range.

If simpl5 has a debug mode, You could try enabling it, maybe that could lead to some clues, too.